# How to implement a MS Teams bot with out using the node.js framework?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to get the following to generate a simple hero card to insert into a conversation when a file URL is unfurled. I do not want to use the node.js bot framework because my end goal is to not use node.js but to directly implement this inside an Apache module.

The following results in a card being inserted into the conversation, but not the one I want. I am not sure what kind of card it is but it is not the correct  one. I assume that the problem is that my reply is not correctly formatted and so it is confusing Teams. Can anyone tell me what is missing?

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('my.net.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('my.net.crt')
};


const server = https.createServer(options , function(req,res) {

    if (req.method == "POST"){
        var body = ''
        req.on('data', chunk => {
            body += chunk.toString();
        });

        req.on('end', () =>{
            var j = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log("url: ", j.value.url);
            card = {
                contentType: 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero',
                content: {
                    title: 'Hello World' ,
                    subtitle:'URL: ' + j.value.url,
                    text: 'This should be a Hero card!'
                }
            }
            const result = {
                attachmentLayout: 'list',
                type: 'result',
                attachments: [card]
            };

            const response = {
                composeExtension: result
            };
            content = JSON.stringify(response);
            res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" , 'Content-Length': content.length  });

            res.end(content);
        });
    }
});

server.listen(443, function() {
    console.log( "listening ");
});
```

Comment: To solve this issue, I need to know your use case for the card so I can suggest you the right card. You can also look for adaptive card it gives great flexibility to create your own card for more info [here](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/)

Comment: After doing more testing I have decided that this code does work but there seems to be a timing issue. If I insert the URL and wait a few seconds, then the correct card is inserted. If I do not wait before hitting enter I get a generic URL preview. If I then insert the same URL again Teams seems to fetch the card from cache and the correct card is displayed. I have seem this behavior when using the bot framework also.